# How to use balanced parenthesis algorithm to replace words from a javascript string?

Tags: javascript, string

Let's consider we have a string named **str**, which is defined as :

```
var str = "I want to replace( this & ( this ) )"
```

Now, I did something like this :

```
str = str.replace(/replace\((.*?)\)/gm, function(_, a) {
  console.log("Replacing : " + a)
  return "it !"
}
```

Output :

```
// In Console
Replacing : this & ( this
// Returned
I want to it ! )
```

But, I wanted the output as :

```
// In Console
Replacing : this & ( this )
// In Return
I want it !
```

I heard about the *Balanced Parenthesis Algorithm*. Therefore can this help me to solve this task ? If yes, how ? What if, there are more brackets in the string ? If no, how can this be done ?

Comment: removing the "?" would give your result, but regex is not a good way to parse balanced parenthesis.

Comment: Then how can I do it without regex ?

Comment: @ASDFGerte I corrected it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const str = "I want to replace ( this & ( this ) )"

const withoutPlaceholder = [str.split('to replace')[0], 'it!'].join('')
// output: I want it!

const withoutAllParenthesis = str.split(/\(([^)]+)\)/)
  .find(strPart => !strPart.includes('(') && !strPart.includes(')')) + ' it!'
// output: I want to replace it!

const balancedParenthesis = XRegExp.matchRecursive(str, '\\(', '\\)', 'g')[0]
const withoutBalancedParenthesis = str.split(balancedParenthesis).join('it!')
// output: I want to replace (it!)

console.log(withoutPlaceholder)
console.log(withoutAllParenthesis)
console.log(withoutBalancedParenthesis)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xregexp/3.2.0/xregexp-all.js"></script>
```

related questions and answers:
- [Regular expression to match balanced parentheses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/546433/regular-expression-to-match-balanced-parentheses)